# What does the "TEST" variable do in Caffe example code?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

In the C++ [example provided by Caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp) they use the variable "TEST" on line 56. I haven't seen it referenced before or after so I was wondering if anyone knew what the variable does?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't download the whole project to find the definition of that constant (not variable) but the comments say there are two constants TEST and TRAIN indicating the "phase".

They must be defined (and maybe commented further) in one of the many Caffe hpp files.

Comment: Ah! So if it was explicitly using the Caffe namespace then it would look like caffe::TEST?